# Vertical skip after ToC heading using tocloft with titles option

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, vertical-alignment, titlesec, tocloft

I'm using `titlesec` to control the appearance of headers (`\section` and friends) in a larger document, and I'm now investigating `tocloft` to adjust the appearance of the table of contents (ToC) as well. Since I'd like for the ToC's own heading to use the same style as the remaining sections, I'm loading `tocloft` with the `titles` option.

This is working fine, but now I'm finding myself wanting to add some vertical space after the ToC heading (and *only* after that); for the sake of the argument suppose it's a `\bigskip`. Usually (i.e. without `titles`), one could just renew `\cftaftertoctitle` in an appropriate manner; but with the `titles` option, `tocloft` offloads the formatting of ToC heading to LaTeX entirely, so this is a no-op then.

Here's an FMWE (Fairly Minimal Working Example) where the more elaborate `\section`formatting has been replaced by something very simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[rigidchapters,explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filcenter}{}{0pt}{{\LARGE\bfseries\scshape #1}}[\filcenter]
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

% ToC customization
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\end{lrbox}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{0.75em}
\cftsetindents{section}{0pt}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\large\bfseries}
\setlength\cftsecindent{3.3em}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\hspace*{3.3em}}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\bigskip}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{This}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{That}
    \lipsum[2]
    \section{Something completely different}
    \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The line that's not doing what it's supposed to here is

`\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\bigskip}`

of course. To illustrate, here's three screenshots (for easy visual comparison, open these in new tabs and switch back and forth between them).

First, with `titles` in effect, and with the extra `\bigskip`:

[image]

Second, with `titles` in effect, but *without* the extra `\bigskip`:

[image]

Third, *without* `titles`, and with the extra `\bigskip`:

[image]

And finally, *without* `titles`, but *without* the extra `\bigskip`:

[image]

As you can see, the `\bigskip` has an effect without `titles` but not with it. This isn't a surprise, it's how `tocloft` is intended to work, but --- how *do* I get some extra vertical space after the ToC's heading if `titles` is in effect?

BTW: feel free to suggest alternatives to `tocloft` as well, I'm not too hung up on it and would actually prefer a more usable, less cryptic package (and with a better manual). `titlesec`, OTOH, I really want to keep.

Thanks!

Comment: So what suggestions do you have to make the package more usable, less cryptic and a better manual? The manual has 13 pages for the general user and 30 pages of documented package code.

Comment: @PeterWilson More examples, for one, that's the biggest thing. With pretty much anything and everything I've wanted to do I had to google how to do it because I couldn't tell from reading the documentation. I'm sure it's fine for someone who already knows the package well, but not for someone who's unfamiliar with it and who's not a (La)TeX pro at that. YMMV.

Comment: The manual contains approximately 30 examples. How many more do you want? What examples do you think are missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not willing to have this discussion. I take it you're the author of `tocloft`? If so I'm sorry if you felt I was needlessly disparaging your package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Use `\usepackage{tocloft}` (no `titles`)

(2) Format the ToC title exactly like the section titles of the document.

(3) Center the ToC title using `\hfill` in `\cfttoctitlefont`  **and** in `\cftaftertoctitle`

(4) Add vertical space in `\cftaftertoctitle`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[rigidchapters,explicit]{titlesec}

\usepackage{tocloft} % use this <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filcenter}{}{0pt}{{\LARGE\bfseries\scshape #1}}[\filcenter]
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

%%% ToC customization
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}
    \renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{\end{lrbox}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{0.75em}
\cftsetindents{section}{0pt}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\large\bfseries}
\setlength\cftsecindent{3.3em}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\hspace*{3.3em}}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\LARGE\bfseries\scshape} % added <<<<<
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill\vspace{50pt}} % inserting a large space <<<<

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{This}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{That}
    \lipsum[2]
    \section{Something completely different}
    \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll leave the question open for a little longer before accepting.